# How to make iTerm3 beta send text at start after change profile automatically?

Tags: iterm2

iTerm has a feature "Automatic Profile Switching", and "Send text at start".

When I open a new window with the special profile, iTerm will send the command that "send text at start" at beginning. But if I setting the "Automatic Profile Switching" and make it work, iTerm change the profile but does not send the text.

How can I fix that? I wanna let iTerm send several commands when I in the special folder during using the same window.

Comment: I have the exactly same use case. Whenever I switch to a folder I want to activate a python virtual environment. I want to do it only once when I do that the first time, so I am using Profile instead of triggers but facing the same issue.